# Any idea to create masked text box in uwp

Tags: win-universal-app, maskedtextbox

Currently I got a requirement to implement a control something like traditional masked text box. But unfortunately there is no first party control (some third party paid control is available like Component 1) available in uwp. If anybody has any idea to create the same please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a TextBox background transparent and have a TextBlock behind it with your watermark text. Bind the visibility to the TextBox Text.IsEmpty property using a BooleanToVisibilityConverter

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Background="White">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3"
                Foreground="SteelBlue"
                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">Type in here...</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Background="Transparent"
                x:Name="MyTextBox"/>
</Grid>
```

In your resources:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

Comment: See my above comments, actual requirement is to implement masked text box, which is very similar to earlier control from win form. See here for details
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have posted the same question in msdn forum, and got some idea to implement the same using behavior. Here is my post
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d4153624-29df-4980-94f1-f5eb4328859c/uwpany-idea-to-create-masked-text-box-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [PlaceHolderText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.placeholdertext.aspx) Property on TextBox control.

Comment: Sorry for confusion occurred. Actual requirement is not about water mark/ placeholder text. I need to implement a masked text box kind of control in uwp. For reference see this control from win form
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx